# Multi-color track in SfRangeSlider in Flutter

Tags: flutter, range, slider, syncfusion, rangeslider

I am using SfRangeSlider in my app and I need to customize the track of the slider based on the values.

For example:

- the part of the track that represents values until 30 should be green
- the part of the track that represents values from 30 until 60 should be yellow
- the part of the track that represents values from 60 until 90 should be orange
- the part of the track that represents values above 90 should be red

Here is the image of what I want to achieve:
[image]

NOTE: In case the MIN value is bigger than 30, then the green color will not be used in the trackbar. This applies to all colors...

I would appreciate any suggestions/tips/help. Thanks!